# MenuFlyout listbox Wp8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to add a MenuFlyout to lisbox 
this is the code

> xaml

```
    <ListBox Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxobj" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="350" >
                        <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton"
                                                Text="Edit"
                                                Click="EditButton_Click"
                                                        />
                                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                                Text="Delete"
                                                        />
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,0" Grid.Row="3" x:Name="CreateddateTxt" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

> C#

```
    private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

            flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
        }

        private async void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(test));
}
```

At first, when I am holding the item it works and show me menu and go the another page, but when I am holding again the same item the app crashes.

Comment: Have you debuged your code? What exception do you get?

Comment: I don't believe that the error is in the page that contains the listview, i think it in the page you are navigating to. Please provide more details about the exception you are getting by debugging your code and using break points.

Comment: there is no exception show, just the app crashes, event if I don't add the event, the 1st time holding work, and the 2nd on the same item crash the app

Comment: sometimes work and other no, I don't know where is the error

Comment: ok, what output do you see in the output window in visual studio?

Comment: In Windows Phone UX Guidelines, it says that when the app throws and exception not caught by your code, then the app should crash to the start screen. So your app is throwing an exception which is causing it to crash.

Comment: sorry for late response, the code works, but the problem that the item was selected as null, and that crash the app